# 2d char array from a file

Tags: java, char, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read in a string from a file, extract individual characters and use those characters to fill a 2D char array. So far I have been able to do everything except fill the array. I keep getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: error message. Any help would be appreciated. This is my first time working with 2D arrays. Thanks.
Here are the contents of the test.txt. Each word on a new line. The first 2 integers are the dimensions of the array
4 4
FILE
WITH
SOME
INFO

```
public class acsiiArt 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
File file = new File("test.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
int x = inputFile.nextInt(); 
int y = inputFile.nextInt(); 
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{ 
char [][] array = new char [x][y];

   //char c = words.charAt(i);  
    for (int row =0; row<x;row++)
    {
        for (int col =0; col<y;col++)
        {
            String words = inputFile.nextLine();
            for (int i=0; i<words.length(); i++)

            array[x][y]=words.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}

}   
 }
```

Comment: Please post some content in test.txt. Actually, I think 2 places need to be modified. 1. Regarding the 2 for-loop. Variables row and col are used. why don't you use them. Change array[x][y]=words.charAt(i) to array[row][col]=words.charAt(i); 2. Put the following code out side of while-loop. char [][] array = new char [x][y];

Comment: 4 4
FILE
WITH
SOME
INFO

here are the contents.each word is a new line and the 2 integers are the dimensions of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int row =0; row<x;row++)
{
    for (int col =0; col<y;col++)
    {
        String words = inputFile.nextLine();
        for (int i=0; i<words.length(); i++)

        array[x][y]=words.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

The total number of indices in `array` is `x * y`.  Below, you are filling all the possible indices

```
for (int row =0; row<x;row++)
{
    for (int col =0; col<y;col++)
```

So when you add this:

```
for (int i=0; i<words.length(); i++)
```

you multiplying another factor `words.length`.  So you need `x * y * words.length` number of indices, but you only have `x * y`. Thats why you're getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoudsException`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems like this and I'm assuming that `x` and `y` are being initialized to the first two characters which represent the number of rows and the number of columns. If that is the case, then third for loop `for (int i=0; i<words.length(); i++)` is unnecessary. You can just reffer to the `col` variable for the word at that point, since it should represent how many characters there are.

**All of this is only applicable if the chars are in a rectangular pattern, meaning that there are the same number of columns in every row. Otherwise you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsError` as soon as one of the lines is shorter than the the column value initially given.**

**Edit**: If you're final 2d char array is not meant to be rectangular and instead "jagged," a different implementation is required. I'd recommend either a 2d `arrayList` (an arrayList of arrayLists).

Or you can keep your current implementation with the third for loop, but you have to be sure that the original `x` value represents the longest row/most amount of columns, and then you'd be able to deal with each row indivually with `words.length`. You'd also have to be fine with the extra portions of the lines that have  a length>`x` having spaces initialized to `null`.

Comment: In java, 2d arrays are supposed to be able to be jagged. This is something java programmers should learn how to use.

Comment: Alright, I've just never jagged arrays and it complicates things. Yes though, you are right, jagged arrays can be used and I should have put more information about that option.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are using array beyond its limit. So in your case:

```
char [][] array = new char [x][y];
//char c = words.charAt(i);  
for (int row =0; row<x;row++) {
    for (int col =0; col<y;col++){
        String words = inputFile.nextLine();
        for (int i=0; i<words.length(); i++)
           array[x][y]=words.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Problem may be because your array size is less then input `words`. problem is because you are putting extra loop, and your loop it self is not correct. Please seen code below.
 So you can do 2 things.

1. change value of `y` large enough so that any word string can store.
2. rather than looping on size of word you can loop on your array size like.

.

```
for (int row =0; row<x;row++) {   
    String words = inputFile.nextLine();
    int size = Math.min(words.length(),y);
    for (int i=0; i< size; i++)
         array[row][i]=words.charAt(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with an `ArrayList<char[]>`. All you have to do is add a new `char[]` for each new line read:

```
ArrayList<char[]> chars = new ArrayList<>();
while (inputFile.hasNext()){
    chars.add(inputFile.nextLine().toCharArray());
}
char[][] array = chars.toArray(new char[chars.size()][]);
```

An `ArrayList` is basically an array of changeable size. This code takes each line in the file, turns it into a `char[]`, then adds it to the `ArrayList`. At the end, it converts the `ArrayList<char[]>` into a `char[][]`.

If you can't or don't want to use `ArrayList`, you could always do this:

```
char[][] array = new char[1][];
int a = 0;
while(inputFile.hasNext()){
    //read line and convert to char[]; store it.
    array[a] = inputFile.nextLine().toCharArray();

    //if there are more lines, increment the size of the array.
    if (inputFile.hasNext()){
        //create a clone array of the same length.
        char[][] clone = new char[array.length][];
        //copy elements from the array to the clone. Note that this can be 
        //done by index with a for loop
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, clone, 0, array.length);
        //make array a new array with an extra char[]
        array = new char[array.length + 1][];
        //copy elements back.
        System.arraycopy(clone, 0, array, 0, clone.length);
        a++;
    }
}
```

If you know the dimensions of the array beforehand:

```
char[][] array = new char[dimension_1][];
int a = 0;
while (inputFile.hasNext()){
    array[a] = inputFile.nextLine().toCharArray();
    a++; //don't need to check if we need to add a new char[]
}
```

---

In response to comment:

We know that a `char[][]` cannot be printed with `Arrays.toString()` (if we want the contents) because we will get a lot of `char[].toString()`. However, a `char[][]` can be printed with one of the following methods:

```
public static String toString(char[][] array){
    String toReturn = "[\n";
    for (char[] cArray: array){
        for (char c: cArray){
            toReturn += c + ",";
        }
        toReturn += "\n";
    }
    return toReturn + "]";
}
```

I personally prefer this one (requires `import java.util.Arrays`):

```
public static String toString(char[][] array){
    String toReturn = "[\n";
    for (char[] cArray: array){
        toReturn += Arrays.toString(cArray) + "\n";
    }
    return toReturn + "]";
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the first method you suggested with the arrayList. In order to print out the newly created 2D array will I just have to  use the usual for loops to go through each row and column.

Comment: Yes. Or you could make a custom method (see post)